Выделение строки в таблице pyqt5, через стилизацию css
Есть интерфейс, написанный на pyqt5, и отдельный css файл в котором задается стиль приложения. Я пытаюсь реализовать выделение строки таблицы при наведении на строку. Но пока что удалось сделать только выделение по отдельности строки таблицы и её номера. Как сделать одновременное выделение и строки и номера строки?
Файл CSSstyle.css:
QWidget#MainWindow{
    background-image: url("backgroundimg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

QLabel{
    color: #e4f1fe;
    }

QWidget#horizontalLayoutWidget{
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }

QWidget#verticalLayoutWidget{
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

QPushButton{    /* Общая настройка кнопок */
    background: #22313f;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #e4f1fe;
}

QPushButton:pressed{
    background-color: #556478;
    border-style: inset;
}

QTableWidget{
    selection-background-color: #556478;
    background: #2a323b;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #fff;
}

QHeaderView:section:hover, QTableWidget:item:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 156, 156, 0.8);
}

QHeaderView::section{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2a313b;
    border: 1px solid #22313f;
    
}
QHeaderView{
    background: #2a313b;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
}   

Конкретно следующие строчки файла отвечают за выделение элементов таблицы:
QHeaderView:section:hover, QTableWidget:item:hover{
    background-color: rgba(255, 156, 156, 0.8);
}

Файл интерфейса Qt5Interface.py:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(600, 600)


        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


        #Контейнеры
        #Контейнер верхних кнопок
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 30))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setObjectName("hbox")
        
        #Контейнер для боковых кнопок
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(543, 39, 57, 340))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.vbox.setObjectName("vbox")


        #Кнопки
        #Back
        self.back_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.back_button.setFlat(True)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons/back-left.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.back_button.setIcon(icon)
        self.back_button.setObjectName("back_button")

        #Forward
        self.Forward_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.Forward_button.setFlat(True)
        self.Forward_button.setObjectName("Forward_button")

        #Разделитель
        self.separator_vertical_1 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.separator_vertical_1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.separator_vertical_1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.separator_vertical_1.setObjectName("separator_vertical_1")

        #Save
        self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.save_button.setFlat(True)
        self.save_button.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons/save.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.save_button.setIcon(icon1)
        self.save_button.setObjectName("save_button")

        #Разделитель снова
        self.separator_vertical_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.separator_vertical_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.separator_vertical_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.separator_vertical_2.setObjectName("separator_vertical_2")

        #Cut
        self.cut_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.cut_button.setFlat(True)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons/cut.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.cut_button.setIcon(icon2)
        self.cut_button.setObjectName("cut_button")

        #Copy
        self.Copy_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.Copy_button.setFlat(True)
        self.Copy_button.setObjectName("Copy_button")

        #Paste
        self.paste_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.paste_button.setFlat(True)
        self.paste_button.setObjectName("paste_button")

        #Change
        self.change_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.change_button.setFlat(True)
        self.change_button.setObjectName("change_button")

        #Разделитель снова снова
        self.separator_vertical_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.separator_vertical_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.separator_vertical_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.separator_vertical_3.setObjectName("separator_vertical_3")

        # Down (сам ты даун)
        self.down_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.down_button.setFlat(True)
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons/arrow-down.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.down_button.setIcon(icon4)
        self.down_button.setObjectName("down_button")

        #UP
        self.Up_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.Up_button.setFlat(True)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons/arrow-up.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.Up_button.setIcon(icon3)
        self.Up_button.setObjectName("Up_button")

        #Разделитель снова снова снова
        self.separator_vertical_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.separator_vertical_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.separator_vertical_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.separator_vertical_4.setObjectName("separator_vertical_4")

        # Delete line
        self.Delete_line_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.Delete_line_button.setFlat(True)
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Icons/trash.svg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.Delete_line_button.setIcon(icon5)
        self.Delete_line_button.setObjectName("Delete_line_button")

        # Delete all
        self.Delete_all_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.Delete_all_button.setFlat(True)
        self.Delete_all_button.setIcon(icon5)
        self.Delete_all_button.setObjectName("Delete_all_button")

        #Разделитель снова снова снова снова
        self.separator_vertical_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.separator_vertical_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.separator_vertical_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.separator_vertical_5.setObjectName("separator_vertical_5")

        # Stop
        self.Stop_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.Stop_button.setFlat(True)
        self.Stop_button.setObjectName("Stop_button")

        #Play
        self.play_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.play_button.setFlat(True)
        self.play_button.setCheckable(True) #Отвечает за то, будет кнопка вжимаемой
        self.play_button.setObjectName("play_button")


        #Добавление верхних кнопок в контейнер
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.back_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.Forward_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.separator_vertical_1)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.save_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.separator_vertical_2)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.cut_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.Copy_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.paste_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.change_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.separator_vertical_3)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.down_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.Up_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.separator_vertical_4)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.Delete_line_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.Delete_all_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.separator_vertical_5)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.Stop_button)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.play_button)


        #Таблица биндов
        table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 39, 484, 340))
        table.setColumnCount(1)
        table.setRowCount(10)
        table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)


        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Column 1"])
        table.horizontalHeader().hide()

        table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        table.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Нажать S"))
        table.setItem(1, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Перейти к n строке"))
        table.setItem(2, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Повторять n количество раз"))

        #Боковые кнопки
        self.Button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_1.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
        self.Button_1.setObjectName("Button_1")

        self.Button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_2.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
        self.Button_2.setObjectName("Button_2")

        self.Button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_3.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
        self.Button_3.setObjectName("Button_3")

        self.Button_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_4.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
        self.Button_4.setObjectName("Button_4")

        self.Button_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_5.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
        self.Button_5.setObjectName("Button_5")

        self.Button_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_6.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
        self.Button_6.setObjectName("Button_6")

        self.Button_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Button_7.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
        self.Button_7.setObjectName("Button_7")


        # Добавление боковых кнопок в контейнер
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.Button_1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.Button_2)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.Button_3)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.Button_4)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.Button_5)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.Button_6)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.Button_7)

        #Верхняя менюшка
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        #Пока что закомментил, мб снесём это и сделаем по лучше
        '''
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 490, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        self.menuSettings = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuSettings.setObjectName("menuSettings")

        self.menuProfile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuProfile.setObjectName("menuProfile")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuSettings.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuProfile.menuAction())


        #Доабавление в меню комманды
        self.NewProfadd = QtWidgets.QAction("Create new")
        self.SettingsProf = QtWidgets.QAction("Profile settings")

        self.Openfilesettings = QtWidgets.QAction("Open file")
        self.SaveFile = QtWidgets.QAction("Save file")
        self.SaveFileAs = QtWidgets.QAction("Save file as")
        self.SettingsMenuOpen = QtWidgets.QAction('Settings')
        self.FaqButton = QtWidgets.QAction('FAQ')
        self.Exitbutton = QtWidgets.QAction('Exit')

        self.menuProfile.addAction(self.NewProfadd)
        self.menuProfile.addAction(self.SettingsProf)

        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.Openfilesettings)
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.SaveFile)
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.SaveFileAs)
        self.menuSettings.addSeparator()    #Отделитель
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.SettingsMenuOpen)
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.FaqButton)
        self.menuSettings.addAction(self.Exitbutton)

'''
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Биндяра(pyqt5)"))
        self.Forward_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "forward"))
        self.Copy_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "copy"))
        self.paste_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "paste"))
        self.change_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "change"))
        self.play_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Play"))
        self.Stop_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "stop"))
        self.Delete_all_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "All"))
        self.Delete_line_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Line"))
        self.Button_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Задержка"))
        self.Button_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Переходник"))
        self.Button_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Цикл"))
        self.Button_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Комментарий"))
        self.Button_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "$Цвет$"))
        self.Button_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Язык"))
        self.Button_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "$Пере$"))
        #self.menuSettings.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
        #self.menuProfile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Profile"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    with open("CSSstyle.css", "r") as file:
        app.setStyleSheet(file.read())
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



А где HTML разметка? Если есть css, значит есть и HTML? Зачем здесь фаил интерфейса?

Я в Pyqt5 новичок, и не сильно разбираюсь в том, используется ли в нем разметка через html при создании приложения. Но по идее файл интерфейса и содержит всю разметку, и внутри файла интерфейса можно применять по отдельности к каждому элементу setStyleSheet, или применить её в конце из отдельного файла/самому прописать.
